# Uninitialized constant RailsAdmin::Config::HasDescription (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I did a bundle update on Rails Admin gem - now it is showing following error when I am trying to start the rails server:

```
/Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config/sections/base.rb:16:in `<class:Base>': uninitialized constant RailsAdmin::Config::HasDescription (NameError)
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config/sections/base.rb:10:in `<module:Sections>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config/sections/base.rb:8:in `<module:Config>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config/sections/base.rb:7:in `<module:RailsAdmin>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config/sections/base.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config/sections/list.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.3/lib/rails_admin/config/model.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails_admin_nestable-0.2.0/lib/rails_admin_nestable.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/nirav/Projects/app-name/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
from /Users/nirav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here is my rails_admin.rb (initializer)

http://pastebin.com/GEPvBqca

Any ideas how to go about solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Update 1 - Here is my routes.rb:

http://pastebin.com/4UGqjnD1

Here is the summary of routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :admins

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  mount RailsAdminImport::Engine => '/rails_admin_import', :as => 'rails_admin_import'

  devise_for :users

  root :to => redirect('/admin')
```

Comment: Have you removed the rails_admin generated route from config/routes.rb ??

Comment: can you post `config/routes.rb` ?

Comment: here it is: http://pastebin.com/4UGqjnD1 (also added it in the answer.)

Comment: Sorry not authorized to access site at my workplace.. it will be better if you post it in your question

Comment: Can you access Pastie? http://pastie.org/9542044

Comment: Hi, added routes.rb summary

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
devise_for :admins
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/rails_admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

I am not sure but I hope it works for you...Don't forget to restart your server..

Comment: Hi Gagan, the same thing is there in my routes.rb file. Tried to tweak that, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry then I haven't any idea as I haven't use this before.. Uninstall it and then try again to install..